# Trying to export vector shapefile as eps file from ArcMap to CorelDraw?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to export a complex shapefile from ArcMap 10.4 into Coreldraw X6. I have already exported other shapefiles by exporting the map as an eps. file and then importing it into CorelDraw which works fine. This one layer won't work though and I get the error 'An error occured while processing .eps. The file cannot be opened.' It is a shapefile with ~12000 small polygons so I have tried removing the tiniest ones and now have ~7000, but this still won't work.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone have any advice?

I also tried saving it and importing it as an ai. file but that won't work either.